# Redux FlatList does not display the object correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i'm using redux with react native and i have a flatlist to display but it does not display the title or description of the object. It displays on screen all the rows of the object but when i call the title for example it does not display it. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FlatList,Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class LibraryList extends Component {

renderItem(library) {
  return <ListItem library={library} />;

}

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.libraries}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={library => library.id.toString()}
       />

    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { libraries: state.libraries }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

ListItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common';

class ListItem extends Component{
  render() {
      return(
        <CardSection>
          <Text>
          {this.props.library.title}
          </Text>
        </CardSection>
      );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```

Comment: Are you getting library value in `renderItem(library)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to say, could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your renderItem function by just putting curly braces in the arguments and specify library object within that here is the example

`

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MyListItem
      id={item.id}
      onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
      selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
      title={item.title}
    />
  ); `
```